# not_analyzed field with doc_values still in fielddata cache

Tags: mapping, elasticsearch

During some experiment with [fielddata vs doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/blog/support-in-the-wild-my-biggest-elasticsearch-problem-at-scale), I encountered a weird case. In my earlier mapping, I didn't use doc values at all. In my new mapping, I've added `doc_values: true` to all fields in my mapping, except analyzed string fields and booleans ([not supported until 2.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7851)).

So in details, here is how I proceeded:

Before reindexing all my data, I restarted my ES 1.7 cluster fresh and ran a query with sorting, aggregations and script fields to "warm up" the fielddata cache. Then I queried the `/fielddata` endpoint to have an idea of the fielddata cache usage. It looked something like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/fielddata?v&fields=*'

id      host   ip            node  total  items.desc.raw more_fields...
rKX7... myhost 192.168.1.100 Doom  32.9mb 2.3mb          ...
```

As you can see, the field `items.desc.raw` used 2.3mb of heap space. `items` is of type `nested` and contains a string multi-field with a `not_analyzed` sub-field called `raw`. In short, the mapping of that nested field looks like this:

```
    "items": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "desc": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

After adding `doc_values: true` to `items.desc.raw`, reindexing the whole index and running some aggregations, sorting and scripting again to warm up the fielddata cache, I queried the `/fielddata` endpoint again and here was the result:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/fielddata?v&fields=*'

id      host   ip            node  total  items.desc.raw some_bools...
tAB5... myhost 192.168.1.100 Yack  2.1mb  9.2kb          ...
```

So the fielddata usage has indeed been drastically lowered (which is good), the only fields I see are boolean fields (i.e. `some_bools` above) which was expected, but to my surprise, my nested `not_analyzed` string field also appeared, but with a much lower space usage.

What could be the cause of `items.desc.raw` still appearing in the fielddata cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow I forgot about [global ordinals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata-formats.html#_global_ordinals). They are the reason why I'm still getting fielddata usage even after using `doc_values` as global ordinals cannot be included in `doc_values`.

See [more details here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/not-analyzed-field-with-doc-values-still-in-fielddata-cache/26298)