# Elasticsearch doc value set to true but still using field data

Tags: caching, elasticsearch

We have no need for using field data, and following Elasticsearch recommendations we've set all fields with "doc_values=true", and set all fields to be not analyzed:

```js
"field1": {
  "index": "not_analyzed",
  "fielddata": {
    "format": "doc_values"
  },
  "doc_values": true,
  "type": "string"
},
"field2": {
  "index": "not_analyzed",
  "fielddata": {
    "format": "doc_values"
  },
  "doc_values": true,
  "type": "date"
},
"field3": {
  "index": "not_analyzed",
  "fielddata": {
    "format": "doc_values"
  },
  "doc_values": true,
  "type": "string"
}
```

Looking at a new index which was created after making the template changes, we see that the field is still using the field data memory (using stats API):

```js
"fielddata" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 30484,
          "evictions" : 0,
          "fields" : {
            "itemCached" : {
              "memory_size_in_bytes" : 7980
            },
            "field1" : {
              "memory_size_in_bytes" : 1248
            },
            "field2" : {
              "memory_size_in_bytes" : 3040
            },"field3" : {
              "memory_size_in_bytes" : 3040
            }
            "field4" : {
              "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0
            ....
          }
```

(other fields are also set as not-analyzed and doc-values=true are also included in the above response).
Can anyone suggest why these fields are still using field data?

Comment: My Q&A here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623636/not-analyzed-field-with-doc-values-still-in-fielddata-cache

Comment: Seems it is the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I learned that due to global ordinals it's apparently not possible to completely divest from field data usage.